# How to set the values of a dataframe given a series of indices and corresponding column names?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Assume I have a dataframe df1:

```
            A    B    C    D    E 
Date                               
2009-01-30  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-02  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-03  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-04  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-05  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-06  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-09  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

and a Series:

```
Date
2009-02-04 A
2009-02-06 E
```

is there a fast vectorized view to set the index/columns values in df1 so as to obtain df2:

```
            A    B    C    D    E 
Date                               
2009-01-30  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-02  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-03  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-04  1    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-05  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-06  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1
2009-02-09  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2009-02-10  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, columns=list('ABCDE'), index=pd.to_datetime(
    ['2009-01-30', '2009-02-02', '2009-02-03', '2009-02-04', '2009-02-05',
    '2009-02-06', '2009-02-09', '2009-02-10']))
ser = pd.Series(list('AE'), index=pd.to_datetime(['2009-02-04', '2009-02-06']))
freqs = pd.get_dummies(ser)
freqs = freqs.where(freqs != 0, np.nan)
result = df1.add(freqs, fill_value=0)

print(result)
```

---

[pd.get_dummies](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.core.reshape.get_dummies.html#pandas-core-reshape-get-dummies) can be used to convert your Series into a frequency table:

```
In [117]: freqs = pd.get_dummies(ser)
In [118]: freqs = freqs.where(freqs != 0, np.nan)

In [119]: freqs
Out[119]: 
col_0        A   E
row_0             
2009-02-04   1 NaN
2009-02-06 NaN   1
```

and the [`DataFrame.add` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html#pandas-dataframe-add) can be used to add these values to `df1`:

```
In [124]: df1.add(freqs, fill_value=0)
Out[124]: 
             A   B   C   D   E
2009-01-30 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2009-02-02 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2009-02-03 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2009-02-04   1 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2009-02-05 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2009-02-06 NaN NaN NaN NaN   1
2009-02-09 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2009-02-10 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: Thx, so there is no way to index it using dates and column names or to use df.apply()? With an index it would be an elegant approach, e.g. df.index(the_series)=1

Comment: There might be, but AFAIK, there is no way to use bracket indexing `df1[...]` or any of the indexers like `.loc[]`, `.at[]`, or `.ix[]` to accomplish this easily. Each of these returns "rectangular" DataFrames, whereas you want to select a *sequence* of individual values using row and column label coordinates. There is a way to use `df.apply` -- there almost always is -- but I think `apply` should be avoided when possible because it is often a relatively slow alternative. (Under the hood it uses a Python loop which calls a Python function for each row or each column... a recipe for slowness.)

Comment: Of course, any non-apply-based solution may also be slow, so it pays to benchmark...